# How to create another column to all child folders of a parent folder in windows file explorer

Tags: windows

There are many folders within the main folder (Parent) and each sub-folder (child) contains many videos. In windows explore I wanted to add an extra column for the duration of each video and I wanted this to happen for all subfolders.

Comment: like thiS? https://youtu.be/wtq1huHaIh4

Answer (score 0):

1. - At the time of writing this answer, I found this video. It gives the solution for the problem
   - Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkGY2Knq_vM
2. If the above video is not present or if it didn't give solution, then here we go..

   - Open the main folder and do right click on columns list bar

[image]

- There first click on more option and in the list of checkboxes choose **length** and press ok

[image]

- Then go to the main folder and click on **view** icon then on **options**

[image]

- After clicking on options, click on **views** tab and at last click **Apply to Folders** button and **OK** button

[image]